# How do i remove a text before the first occurrence of "_" from a string using javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript

How would I remove the text appearing before the first occurrence of the "_"?

```js
var string = "apple_ball_cat_Dog";
var newString = string.split("_").pop();
console.log(newString);
```

**Actual result**: Dog

**Expected result**: ball_cat_Dog

Comment: Actual actual result: `VM67:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: apple_ball_cat_Dog is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
var string = 'apple_ball_cat_Dog';
var newString = string.substring(string.indexOf("_") + 1, string.length);
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have wrap the string inside `quotes` like as use `substring()` and  `indexOf()` function:

```
var string = "apple_ball_cat_Dog";
var result = string.substring(string.indexOf("_") + 1, string.length);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is use the `search` string method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to find the index of the first occurence of `_`, and then `slice` the string on this index + 1, to get only what is after the found index (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
var string = 'apple_ball_cat_Dog';
var index = string.search('_');
var result = string.slice(index + 1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's certainly not nice, but it should work :)

```js
    var string = "apple_ball_cat_Dog";
    var newString = string .replace(string.split("_").shift() + "_", "");
    console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = 'apple_ball_cat_Dog';
var newString = string.split('_');
newString.shift();
newString = newString.join('_');
console.log(newString);
```

There are few things here.
First line has to be an string, original question didn't had it declared as string.

Second line takes the string and splits it into `array`, specifically into 4 elements of array.

Then we need to call `shift()` over that if we want to get rid of the first element. `shift()` by itself will also return the element it removes from array, so we can't use that directly, hence new line.

Then we can join the `newString` which now has only 3 elements, back together with `_` between elements to form new string, returning `ball_cat_Dog`

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var string = 'apple_ball_cat_Dog';
var n = string.split('_');
n.shift();
var new_string = n.length ? n.join('_') : string;
console.log(new_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 var string = "apple_ball_cat_Dog";
        var indx = string.indexOf("_");
        var newString = string.slice(indx+1, string.length);
        alert(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
var string = "apple_ball_cat_Dog";
var result = string.substring(string.indexOf("_") + 1, string.length);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "apple_ball_cat_Dog";
var splited = string.split("_");
var newString = splited.shift() && splited.join("_") 
console.log(newString);
```

should do what you want